# ArgumentError at /user. - Rails 4 Rails_admin Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin, pundit

I am trying to use rails_admin_pundit to add role based access
to rails_admin.

I am getting this error when I click on the users table in the rails_admin.

`ArgumentError at /user. User(id: integer, email: string, ... 'shortened' ...role: integer) is not an ActiveRecord::Relation`

I created an app using:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit

and followed the usage instructions at:
https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit

This is in my `user_policy.rb` just to get things started...

```
def rails_admin?(action)
  case action
    when :destroy, :new
      false
    else
      @current_user.admin!
  end
end
```

Attached are a couple apps with the error, and a screen shot of what I see just before I press the Users model name link.

[app with the error..](https://github.com/dgleba/drails237a-error1)

[error file and screenshot](https://github.com/dgleba/drails237a-error1/tree/master/0errors)

[another app with the same error](https://github.com/dgleba/drail242c-error1)

Not needed: dropbox link...
[link to screenshot, error page, and two apps that I have this problem in...](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bvbmq9pty193hq7/AAC68k8bVkUHJiMAE1-F4__za?dl=0)

- I can get pundit to work outside of rails_admin
- I am logged in as admin
- I have googled the web for this error or similar issues.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

When we generate the code we have:

```
class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
```

So, instead that we need to define the scope

```
class Scope < Scope
  def resolve      
    if @user.role.description == 'admin' 
      User.all
    else
      User.where(id: @user.id)
    end
  end
end
```